# What's the likelihood function in this case?

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I have a data set with a binary response variable as non-zero survival cells (y=0) or zero survival cells (y=1), and I would like to build a model with explanatory variable X. I know that the most straightforward method is to use logistic regression. However, in my case, it is more biologically sound to use a Poisson model. Thus, the number of survived cells follows a Poisson distribution $f(k,\lambda)$, and the response (probability of having zero survival cell) is the Poisson distribution at $k=0$.

Therefore, my model can be written as $y=f(0,\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}$, where $\lambda=g(\beta,x)$. $\lambda$ is a function of $x$ with parameter $\beta$. I am trying to estimate $\beta$ using MLE.

Now I am bit confused about which likelihood function I should use. Shall I assume that $y$ follows a binomial distribution: $y\sim B(1,e^{-\lambda})$, so that I could conduct MLE on the likelihood function from this binomial distribution? What about the Poisson distribution? It is not used in the estimation? Suppose $\beta^{*}$ is the estimated parameter, which gives $\lambda^{*}$. This means that the probability of having zero survival cells follows a $B(1,e^{-\lambda^{*}})$ distribution and the survival cells follows a Poisson $f(k,\lambda^{*})$ distribution?

Comment: Do you have a particular functional form for $g(\beta,x)$ in mind?

Comment: yes, $\lambda=g(\beta,x)=Nexp^{-\beta x}$, where N refers to the original number of cells and $exp^{-\beta x}$ refers to the fraction of cells that are died.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you've distinguished between $p(y=0)$ and $\lambda$, so just to check:  $p(y=0) = \exp\{-\lambda\}$, $\lambda = N\exp\{-\beta x\}$, so $p(y=0) = \exp\{N\exp\{-\beta x\}\}$?

Comment: Yes.That's exactly my model

Comment: Given what you write in your question, $exp(-\lambda)$ is the probability of having zero survival, and zero survival is mapped to $y=1$ (as you write it), not $y=0$. cc @jbowman

Comment: Why would your sample size ($N$) affect the fraction of cells that have died?  The count, perhaps, but the probability?

Comment: @jbowman. I am not sure If I get your questions. $N$ refers to the original number of cells, actually it is also a variable. $N exp^{-\beta x}$ is the cell survival function. I don't think $N$ refers to the sample size.

Comment: "The original number of cells" is the same as what I think jbowman intended by "sample size". I agree with his concern, as well.

Comment: @Glen_b  You're correct, as usual.  To the OP - how does the number of cells $N$ differ from a sample of $N$ cells?  I am assuming whether a cell survives or not is independent, to a reasonable degree of approximation, of the survival of other cells.  My suspicion is that you really mean that the expected number of cells surviving is $N \exp\{-\beta x\}$, which doesn't agree with $\lambda = N \exp\{-\beta x\}$.

Comment: Only $exp^{-\beta x}$ is the probability of cells that have survived, which is irreverent to $N$. So $exp^{-\beta x}$ is the probability. $N exp^{-\beta x}$ gives the counts of cells that that have survived.

Comment: @jbowman, Could you give me more insight about "My suspicion is that you really mean that the expected number of cells surviving is Nexp{−βx}, which doesn't agree with λ=Nexp{−βx}." Why?

Comment: @jbowman, Yes, your concern about in dependency of survival among cell is reasonable. However, we assume that cell survival is independent.

Comment: You have, in one case, the probability of a cell surviving is $\exp\{-\lambda\}$, and in the other case, $\exp\{-\beta x\}$, which is inconsistent with $\lambda = \exp\{-\beta x\}$.

Comment: $exp^{−\lambda}$ is the probability of counting zero survival cells, given the individual cell survival probability $exp^{−\beta x}$ and the expected number of counted survived cell as $Nexp^{−\beta x}$. Are these two definitions the same? I am confused.

Comment: If the individual cell survival probability is $\exp\{-\beta x\}$, then the individual cell non-survival probability is $1 - \exp\{-\beta x\}$.  The probability that no cells out of $N$ survive is just the product of the $N$ (identical) probabilities that each cell fails to survive.  This probability is $(1-\exp\{-\beta x\})^N$.  With your definition of $\lambda$ as $N\exp\{-\beta x\}$, you are getting this probability as $\exp\{-N\exp\{-\beta x\}\}$, which is obviously not the same.

Comment: thanks @jbowman. I checked the two formulas. It seems that these two expressions are equal if $N\rightarrow\infty$, which is true in terms of cells. This is a characteristic of the exponential function: $e^{x}=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}$. In our case: $e^{-\lambda}=e^{-N exp(-\beta x)}=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{N exp(-\beta x)}{N})^{N}$